# Sending Push Notification to multiple android devices using asp .net

Tags: android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to Send Push notifications to multiple android devices.

> For one device its working, but when I tried to add multiple device
>   registrationIDs then its not; GCM returns **Error=InvalidRegistration**

```
var Message = tMessage.Text; //message text box   
            var Title = tTitle.Text;
            string stringregIds = null;
            List<string> regIDs = new List<string>();
            regIDs.Add(redIdEmulNew);
            regIDs.Add(regIdMobileNew);
             stringregIds = string.Join("\",\"", regIDs);   

            WebRequest tRequest;

            tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

            tRequest.Method = "post";

            tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));
            string postData =
             "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
              + Message + "&data.title=" + Title + "&registration_id=" +
                 stringregIds + "";


            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();

            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

            dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();   //Get response from GCM server.

            lbResponse.Text = sResponseFromServer;      //Assigning GCM response to Label text 

            tReader.Close();

            dataStream.Close();
            tResponse.Close();
```

I suspect below code has issue:

```
string stringregIds = null;
List<string> regIDs = new List<string>();
regIDs.Add(redIdEmulNew);
regIDs.Add(regIdMobileNew);
stringregIds = string.Join("\",\"", regIDs);
```

Both device registration Ids are valid, I have checked push notifications  individually.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a long time I found "**Multicast messages (sending to more than 1 registration IDs) are allowed using HTTP JSON format only**"

Here is the reference https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#table1

and an example http://labs.distriqt.com/post/1223

```
string postData =
"{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + stringregIds + "\" ], " +
"\"data\": {\"title\":\"" + Title + "\", " +
"\"message\": \"" + Message + "\"}}";
```

Comment: tRequest.ContentType = " application/json";   - Set the correct format to go with the changes suggested by Ashok.